# ! Error starting UDP server on port 5353, check permissions or other servers running

Tags: python, udp, zsh

I am trying to use Responder.py on MacOS, I am getting issues to do with port 5353.
Im not sure how to solve this as I have already tried using the following commands, any help greatly appreciated.

using this command to start:
(zsh)

```
% sudo python3 Responder.py -I tun0 -i 172.20.10.8

<... LOTS OF OUTPUT ABOVE THAT I WONT INCLUDE UNLESS NECESSARY>
<end of output / where issue is occuring:>

[+] Listening for events...

[!] Error starting UDP server on port 5355, check permissions or other servers running.
[!] Error starting UDP server on port 5353, check permissions or other servers running.
[+] Exiting...
```

172.20.10.8 is the IP of my computer on hotspot wifi, Please let me know if this is the wrong IP to be using for the -i flag.

I have tried this to see whats up:
(zsh)

```
% lsof -i UDP:5353       
COMMAND    PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    2228 maxcooper  109u  IPv6 0xc031b29db4830411      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  112u  IPv6 0xc031b29db4830741      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  116u  IPv6 0xc031b29db4830a71      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  122u  IPv4 0xc031b29db4830da1      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  127u  IPv6 0xc031b29db48310d1      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  131u  IPv6 0xc031b29db4831731      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  132u  IPv6 0xc031b29db4831d91      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  133u  IPv6 0xc031b29db48320c1      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  137u  IPv6 0xc031b29db48323f1      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  138u  IPv6 0xc031b29db4832721      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  144u  IPv6 0xc031b29db4832a51      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  146u  IPv6 0xc031b29db482f0f1      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  147u  IPv4 0xc031b29db482f421      0t0  UDP *:mdns
Google    2228 maxcooper  150u  IPv6 0xc031b29db482f751      0t0  UDP *:mdns
```

followed with this to try kill the process but it doesn't seem to change anything:
(zsh)
`kill -9 2228`

Comment: MacOS already uses port 5353 for the MDNS service. You should pick a different port so you don't interfere with this.

Comment: When you kill the process, I suspect it's automatically restarting it.

Comment: Hi, how can I pick a different Port, This is not my script / application. I am just trying to use it and have default setup modes.

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue on MacOS: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/Responder/issues/124 https://github.com/SpiderLabs/Responder/issues/149